# Virtual Machine not running over genymotion(stuck on initialization tab)

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion, virtual-device-manager

I just started android studio for learning purpose, it has been about a week that I am unable to setup android studio properly to run. 
However I tried every possible solution to make it run, which includes

- Setting up SDK properly
- Setting Virtual Devices to low resolutions
- Went for genymotion to make it run
- Setup AVD properly according to what i seen on this site

Therefore, now switching to Genymotion and setting up all the things properly(e.g Virtual device path, Making Virtual Device), I'm unable to make it run through Android Studio. When i open Genymotion Device Manager(through Android Studio), there is device present which i created in Genymotion, after that when I hit Start button it just stuck on the following "initializing VD" tab
[image: when i hit start from genymotion device manager, it stuck on this]

I have waited for this to complete for 3 hours.
What should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the Virtual Device ON from Genymotion and running it directly from "run selected configuration" from android device worked for me. However turning device on through genymotion device manager still doesn't worked but I made my app run anyhow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a bug in Android Studio startup script (caused by the way it setup the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`variable, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171503). This has been fixed in Android Studio 3.1. If you are using an older version, updating should help.